# How I can store URI value to Storage Reference variabe in Andriod Studio

Tags: java

[Error show in image.Please Click here for view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSQTY.jpg)
When User Want to change his profile picture.and upload new image . Firebase get uri of new image ad replaced with old uri value. That work is done  with .setValue(). Now i am unbale to use that method. Please Any one tell me Solution, how i cando it easily.

```
    enter code here
```

` package junaidandusman.newchatapp;

```
public class SettingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CircleImageView SettingDisplayprofileImage;
    private TextView SettingDisplayName;
    private TextView SettingDisplayStatus;
    private Button SettingChangeprofileImage;
    private Button SettingChangeStatus;
    private DatabaseReference Reference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private final static int Gallery_Pick=1;
    private StorageReference Storagereference;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
        SettingDisplayprofileImage=(CircleImageView) 
        findViewById(R.id.setting_profile_image);
            SettingDisplayName=(TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.setting_username);
            SettingDisplayStatus=(TextView) 
findViewById(R.id.setting_userstatus);
            SettingChangeprofileImage=(Button) 
findViewById(R.id.setting_change_profile_image);
            SettingChangeStatus=(Button) 
findViewById(R.id.setting_change_profile_status);
            Storagereference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profile_images");
            mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            String online_user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            Reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(online_user_id);
            Reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   String name=dataSnapshot.child("user_name").getValue().toString();
                   String status=dataSnapshot.child("user_status").getValue().toString();
                   String image=dataSnapshot.child("user_image").getValue().toString();
                   String thumb_image=dataSnapshot.child("user_thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                   SettingDisplayName.setText(name);
                   SettingDisplayStatus.setText(status);
                }

                @Override
             public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
SettingChangeprofileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent gallery_intent=new Intent();
                    gallery_intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    gallery_intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(gallery_intent,Gallery_Pick);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null){
                Uri Imageuri=data.getData();
                CropImage.activity()
                        .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                        .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                        .start(this);

            }
            if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                    String user_id=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    StorageReference FilePath=Storagereference.child(user_id+".jpg");
                    FilePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this,"Saving your profile image to Firebase Storag",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                                String downloadurl=task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                Storagereference.child("user_image").setValue(downloadurl);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this,"Error occured,while uploading your profile image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                    Exception error = result.getError();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How I can store downloaduri value to Storagereference using .setValue or any other method that can do this?